# What technology do people use to create bots for games like LOL or Runescape?

Tags: computer-vision, game-ai, chat-bots

I was curious about how people make AI to play games. Does anyone know of the AI used to play these games? What allows the AI to see/click the screen in real-time? Even just direction on what libraries for such tasks would be helpful. I can't imagine game developers make an API for creating bots in their games like browsers use with selenium.

Answer (score 3):

Bot development is more about 'hacking' than AI in a way that in the very first place you need to read and (over) write game data which you are not supposed to (and thereby potentially violating the Terms and Conditions - so be aware of that). The AI part is fairly simple for most hack/bot applications that I can think of.

**Read data**

To read game data you can for example:

- use an assembly code debugger like Ollydbg to locate relevant data in the memory, e.g. amount of gold
- Observe graphical objects being rendered, e.g. a unit being drawn
- Intercept network packages containing all kinds of game information, e.g. a unit appearing on your screen

**Write data**

In a similar way there are multiple ways to write data:

- overwrite game data in memory
- Use the Windows API SendInput() function to emulate keyboard inputs
- Use the Windows API SendMessage() function to send messages to the game
- Manipulate network traffic

These lists are not comprehensive but to give you an idea of how it is being done.

AI-wise an A* algorithm for example can be deployed to do path finding.

If you are interested in the topic I suggest to read 'Game Hacking' by Nick Cano. The book provides a good introduction.